# How to check if user has been through a method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a simple text-based RPG in Python. Currently I have two methods for most rooms, one for when they first enter and one if they return. Is there a way that I can make sure that they haven't been in that room before without another method?

For example, if I had a method named `tomb()` i create another method called `tombAlready()` that contains the same code except for the introduction text to the room.

So if I had

```
slow_type("\n\nTomb\n\n")
  slow_type("There is an altar in the middle of the room, with passages leading down and west.")
  choice = None
  while choice == None:
    userInput = input("\n>")
    if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
      while checkDirection == False:
        userInput = input("\n>")
        checkDirection(userInput)
    userInput = userInput.lower().strip()
    if userInput == "d":
      catacombs()
    elif userInput == "n":
      altar()
    elif userInput == "w":
      throneroom()
    else:
      slow_type("You cannot perform this action.")
```

Then `tombAlready()` would have the same code except for `slow_type("There is an altar in the middle of the room, with passages leading down and west.")`

Comment: Global variables?

Comment: where do you propose I define my global variable?

Comment: Add a if statement and a variable that changes from False to True after tombed

Comment: What you want is state associated with a function. Use an object with a method.

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm quite new to Python. Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: @tassar I think I can count the amount of times I've used `global` on one hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is state associated with a function. Use an object with a method:

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, description):
        self._description = description
        self._visited = False

    def visit(self):
        if not self._visited:
            print(self._description)
            self._visited = True
```

Then you can have a `Room` object for each room:

```
catacombs = Room('There is a low, arched passageway. You have to stoop.')
tomb = Room('There is an altar in the middle of the room, with passages leading down and west.')
throneroom = Room('There is a large chair. It looks inviting.')
```

You can visit a room twice but it only prints its description once:

```
>>> catacombs.visit()
There is a low, arched passageway. You have to stoop.

>>> catacombs.visit()
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm :)

Comment: quick question, BTW... if I have my rooms in methods like `catacombs()` would I use the same name for my variable?

Comment: or more specifically, where do I place the variable so it doesn't interfere with the program?